# How does reciprocal of this power series looks like?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, power-series

suppose $f(x)$ looks like $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k+1}a_k x^{-k}$$ with $a_i > 0,\mbox{ i=0,1,2,3...}$

I say it "looks like" as I don't know the exact values of $a_i$.

I want to know how $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ looks like? as a power series. I am interested in the asymptotic as $x\to\infty$

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to have a pleasant, general answer.  Look at $\cos(x)=1-\frac {x^2}{2!}+\frac {x^4}{4!}-\cdots$ for example.  The Taylor expansion of $\sec(x)=\frac 1{\cos(x)}$ isn't straightforward at all.  It's first few terms are $1 + \frac {x^2}2 + \frac {5 x^4}{4!}+ \frac {61 x^6}{6!} + O(x^7)$ and if there is a simple, closed formula for the coefficient in the numerator, I am unaware of it.

Comment: Technically this is not a power series in $x$ because the terms of the series have powers of  $x^{-1}$. But I don't think this makes much difference to working out the reciprocal if you are willing to accept another power series in $x^{-1}$.

Comment: @lulu : I am not interested in the exact formula or coeeficients..I want to know the asymptotic behaviour as $x\to\infty$. I am sure its possible.

Comment: @hardmath : Exactly. Thats what I want.

Comment: Nothing in your post refers to asymptotic behavior.  Please edit to ask the question you intended to ask.

Comment: @lulu : edited.

Comment: Let $t = -1/x$, so $f(x) = g(t) = -\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k t^k$, and $x \to \infty$ corresponds to $t \to 0$.  This is just an ordinary Taylor series.  Assuming the radius of convergence is nonzero, $g$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $0$.  If in addition $a_0 \ne 0$, $1/g$ is also analytic in a neighbourhood of $0$.  So $$\frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{-1}{a_0} + \frac{a_1}{a_0^2} t + \ldots =  \frac{-1}{a_0} - \frac{a_1}{a_0^2} x^{-1} + \ldots $$

Comment: "I don't know the exact values of $a_i$". Sorry, but that sounds like a Russian fairy tale: go there, don't know where, bring that, don't know what.

Comment: @RobertIsrael : makes sense...what I was looking for. Please consider adding this as an answer so that it can be accepted.

Comment: @RobertIsrael : Also, request you to kindly add the case $a_0 = 0$ but $a_1 \ne 0$

Comment: Note that the case $a_0=0$ but $a_1\neq 0$ is reduced to the earlier case by factoring out one copy of $x^{-1}$ (whose reciprocal is easy).

Comment: @hardmath : Ah Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Comment made into an answer as requested by OP]

Let $t=−1/x$, so $f(x)=g(t)=−\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k t^k$, and $x \to \infty$ corresponds to $t \to 0$. This is just an ordinary Taylor series. Assuming the radius of convergence is nonzero, $g$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $0$. If in addition $a_0 \ne 0$, $1/g$ is also analytic in a neighbourhood of $0$. So

$$ \frac{1}{f(x)} = - \frac{1}{a_0} + \frac{a_1}{a_0^2} t + \ldots = -\frac{1}{a_0} - \frac{a_1}{a_0^2} x^{-1} + \ldots $$